# g++ linker undefined reference to only some functions (not all) from shared library

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, g++

I am trying to link to a 3rd party library in linux using g++
my g++ command is

```
g++ -o "outdir/libmyLib.so.1.0" -Wl,--trace-symbol=_foo_bar_baz -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,--verbose obj_a.o obj_b.o foobarwrapper.o   -L/usr/local/lib/foobar `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -Wl,--start-group -llots -lof -ldeps -lfoobar -lz -ldl -lm -Wl,--end-group
```

this yields an undefined reference from the linker

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
1>     Supported emulations:
1>      elf_x86_64
1>      elf32_x86_64
1>      elf_i386
1>      elf_iamcu
1>      i386linux
1>      elf_l1om
1>      elf_k1om
1>      i386pep
1>      i386pe
1>   using internal linker script:
1>   ==================================================
1>   /* Script for --shared -z combreloc -z now -z relro: shared library, combine & sort relocs */
1>   
1>   attempt to open /usr/local/lib/foobar/libfoobar.so succeeded
1>   /usr/local/lib/foobar/libfoobar.so: definition of _foo_bar_baz
1>   /obj/x64/Debug/foobarwrapper.o: In function `foobarwrapper::ThreadEntryRoutine()':
1>   /foobarwrapper.cpp:479: undefined reference to `_foo_bar_baz()'
1>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In total there are about 30 functions that I use from this library, but only 4 of the functions generate the linker error.

I have tried moving the -lfoobar to different places. It either makes no difference or all library functions fail to link.

I have tried adding -lfoobar to the compilation command as per some answers/comments to similar questions, but still no love.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can try to check the exported symbols by e.g. `nm -D C -g libname.so` to see what are the differences.

Comment: @axalis nm lists them all as "T"

Comment: And all the failing function names are there? That would be strange. Recheck also by search (e.g. pipe to `less` and try to search for the particular function names)

Comment: @axalis they are all present and accounted for. piped nm output to grep and ran the so through ida. ida shows the functions are exported and have executable code. I had intended to compare the assembly of the faulty linux and working windows libraries to ensure the provider didnt goof something up, but I grabbed an obsolete version of the windows lib by accident so I will have to do that after work if the issue still isnt resolved.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping the #includes of the headers for the lib with extern "C" {} seems to have done the business.